# Select mid-level attribute from JMESPATH expression

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I am trying to select the cluster name for a specific virtual machine using Ansible's json_query which uses JMESPATH in the backend. 
I have followed the tutorial and examples at http://jmespath.org but am unable to construct the correct query.

My datastructure is as follows:

```
{
"datacenters": [
  {
  "name": "dc-a",
  "clusters": [
    { "name": "cluster-a",

      "hosts": [
        {
          "name": "host-a",
          "vms": [
            {
              "name": "vm-a",
              "summary": {
                "mem": "8",
                "diskGB": "78.00",
                "annotation": "",
                "state": "poweredOn",
                "ostype": "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)",
                "cpu": "2"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "vm-b",
              "summary": {
                "mem": "24",
                "diskGB": "114.00",
                "annotation": "",
                "state": "poweredOn",
                "ostype": "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)",
                "cpu": "4"
              }
            }]
        }]
    }]
 }]
}
```

I am able to select the VM *('vm-a')* using the query below but I am looking for the cluster *(i.e. 'cluster-a')*.

```
datacenters[].clusters[].hosts[].vms[?name=='vm-a'].name[]
```

Comment: No prove on intend, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to learn how to ask properly a question on stackoverflow

Comment: I think is a good enough question. I've certainly seen far worse. Also, this is the first question of the poster, no need to be overly formal here. Let alone downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datacenters[].clusters[?contains(hosts[].vms[].name, 'vm-a')].name[]`